# IS there an error in the calculation

Tags: calculus

if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continous functions and $h(x)=\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{f(x)+x^{2n}g(x)}{1+x^{2n}}$

for $x<-1$ or $x>1,  x^{2n} =\infty$ and hence by dividing through our by $x^{2n}$  the limit is $g(x)$ which is continuous.
 but when $x=1$ or $ -1$,  $x^{2n}=1$ 
the limit becomes $f(x)+g(x)$ which is continuous. But my book says it is discontinuous at $+1$ and $-1$
 please explain

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^{2n} \to 0$ for $|x| < 1$, hence for $|x| < 1$, we have 
$$ h(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) + x^{2n} g(x)}{1 + x^{2n}} = \frac{f(x)}1 = f(x) $$
For $|x| > 1$, we have $x^{2n} \to \infty$, hence 
$$ h(x) =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) + x^{2n} g(x)}{1 + x^{2n}} =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{-2n}f(x) + g(x)}{1 + x^{-2n}} = g(x) $$
Moreover we have 
$$ h(1) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(1) + g(1)}{1 + 1} = \frac{f(1) + g(1)}2 $$
and 
$$ h(-1) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(-1) + g(-1)}{1 + 1} = \frac{f(-1) + g(-1)}2 $$
that is 
$$ h(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & |x| < 1\\
     g(x) & |x| > 1 \\
     \frac 12 \bigl(f(x) + g(x)\bigr) & |x| =  1
\end{cases}
$$
which is continuous at $\pm 1$ if and only if $f(\pm 1) = g(\pm 1)$.